# Как добавить в ArrayList <string> правильно?

Tags: c#, arraylist

```
var pathToFile = Directory.GetFiles(_pathToFileWithListProxy + "/PROXY");

foreach (var member in pathToFile)
{
    if (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(member)== "HTTPS")
    {
        ProxyListHttps.AddRange( File.ReadAllLines(member));
    }
    if (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(member) == "SOCKS4")
    {
        ProxyListSocks4.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(member));
    }
    if (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(member) == "SOCKS5")
    {
        ProxyListSocks5.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(member));
    }
}
```

примечания
В папке могут быть 3 файла с именами HTTPS, SOCKS4, SOCKS5 (а могут и не быть все).
Если такие находят то записать строки из этих файлов в соответствующие `ArrayList <string>`.
Тут ошибку я не понял
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Кто бросает "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"? Какой метод?

Comment: вот эта сволочь
ProxyListHttps.AddRange( File.ReadAllLines(member));

Comment: Закопайте ArrayList обратно. Используйте List. А ещё, вы забыли создать ваши списки при помощи `new`.

Comment: Первые мысли
Что то связанно с статикой код который написал находится в не статический класс.
Код записанный в не статический класс (в конструкторе класса)

Comment: Вы сильно поможете если покажете где пихнуть new ..

Comment: Либо ProxyListHttps (или ProxyListSocks4, или ProxyListSocks5) равно null. Либо ReadAllLines возвращает null, либо member равен null. Что именно - надо выяснять. Я бы File.ReadAllLines(member) вынес в начало цикла, чтобы понять что он возвращает.

Comment: В файлах есть запись, null исключается,

Comment: string[] abc;
                        abc = File.ReadAllLines(member);
                        MessageBox.Show(abc[0]);
Возвращает первую строку, чтение с файла успешно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var pathToFile = Directory.EnumerateFiles(_pathToFileWithListProxy + "/PROXY");
var proxyListHttps = new List<string>();
var proxyListSocks4 = new List<string>();
var proxyListSocks5 = new List<string>();
foreach (var member in pathToFile) {
    switch(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(member)) {
        case "HTTPS":
            proxyListHttps.AddRange(File.ReadLines(member));
            break;
        case "SOCKS4":
            proxyListSocks4.AddRange(File.ReadLines(member));
            break;
        case "SOCKS5":
            proxyListSocks5.AddRange(File.ReadLines(member));
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Уже буду использовать List<T>  вместо ArrayList<T>.
Всем спасибо поменял тип и помогло сделать задуманное.
Буду признателен если кто то объяснит мою ошибку.

Comment: я понял
я присваивал значения переменным proxyList.. значения но я их не инициализировал = new ArrayList ();

Comment: @IgorCeban _"объяснит мою ошибку"_ -- без инициализации, в переменных reference-типов записан null. и при попытке обращения к несуществующему объекту получается exception: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".